# Is Maven used in real projects?

Tags: maven

In my small company Maven is something new. I wonder Is Maven used in real big or larger serious projects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, Maven is used to build most open source Java projects, these days:

Spring, <s>Hibernate</s>, Wicket immediately come to mind, but I'm guessing many more.

Over the last 5 years, I have done contract work for six different companies, ranging in size from about 50 to several hundred developers (counting java developers only). All of them have used Maven exclusively in the time I spent there. Almost all of them had repository servers installed and were developing custom plugins, archetypes, parent poms etc.

Comment: No longer true for Hibernate: [Gradle: why?](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GradleWhy)

Comment: @Tomasz OK, Gradle is pretty awesome too. Scratch Hibernate, then.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap!

Actually, it's used on huge projects. Apache Camel, for example, is based on Maven.
And in telecomunications (where I work), it is widely used too.

It's the best way I know to manage dependency on Java based projects.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked in a large company where we had created a maven build with 150 modules (multimodule build) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a lot of big projects use maven. Just look how many frameworks provide their jars via maven repositories.

In my company every new project is done with maven.

Comment: You don't have to use Maven to provide jars via Maven repository, though it greatly helps.

Answer (score 0):

It still isn't spread too much, but if you look at some of the really big frameworks like spring, most of them already use maven.

On the other hand I worked for a big company as in intern some years ago and I was helping to move their giant project full of legacy code from ant/ivy to maven. In the end it turned out to be extremely annoying because many mirco jobs like creating home and remote interfaces for those EBJ 2.x's (there were like 20+ self-written tasks), were done with specific ant tasks. I ended up using an enormous amout of maven plug-ins to acienve the same results and especially the ant plug-in to run some of that existing stuff.

From this experience, I have taken home that migrating huge projects can be extremely annoying for unspectacular benefits. Maybe this could be a reason why older projects haven't made the move and in conclusion it seems that big projects don't use maven. While maven would be great for them, they started without it and making the change isn't as easy as it is for smaller projects.

Comment: *It still isn't spread too much* ??? You're in Germany too, aren't you? I'm not aware of any German software company that uses Java but doesn't use Maven. Some are currently switching to Maven, but that's about it.

Comment: And I'd argue that projects that can't be migrated to maven probably have a messed up build process anyway.

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd I didn't mean Software Companies in particular. What came to my mind were some projects at banks, insurences and so on. Especially from what some friends have told me, there are plenty projects that currently don't use maven

Comment: yes, that's true. Most of these have ancient infrastructures which are not subject to change. There are a few counter-examples: e.g. the DiBa in Nürnberg is very modern, it uses Wicket as Frontend-Framework, Spring for Backend and Maven / Jenkins for Infrastructure. But I agree, in most cases you are right regarding banks and insurance companies.